# Typed Dataset Calculated Column using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, dataset, calculated-columns

I have a strongly-typed `DataTable` returned in a strongly-typed `DataSet` from a database query. The `DataSet` is subsequently passed to a `ReportViewer` to display a chart based on some aspects of the data.

I've added an extra column to the dataset and I'm looping through the table calculating a value for this new column based on one of the columns returned from the database.

The calculated column is a single byte value which is simply the first element of another column which is an array of bytes.

```
        foreach (ReportData.EventRangeRow row in ReportData.EventRange)
        {
            byte[] analysis = (byte[]) row[ReportData.EventRange.analysisColumn];

            row[ReportData.EventRange.first_analysisColumn] = analysis[0];
        }
```

Obviously my solution works but is a bit unwieldy, so I was wondering whether anyone could suggest a way of either automatically calculating the column as part of the typed dataset or if not, a linq statement which would achieve the same.

Thanks!

Comment: do you need this Calculated value only in reportviewer? perhaps you should just make an expression in the report without modifying the dataset? There are many aggregate functions like Sum,Last,Max,Min, Count etc..

Comment: Hi Martin, I hadn't realised that was possible - if you could point me in the right direction in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do many calculations on the report itself, instead of extending your Dataset.

Let's say you have a datasource "MyDataTable" connected to your report.
Then drag a textbox onto the report and right click on it and then choose Expression and you get a nice window for writing expressions with lots of examples

One aggregate function could be... 
=First(Fields!MyColumn.Value, "MyDataTable")

Check the examples in the window under the category "Common Functions -> Aggregate"

Comment: I assume that you are using Microsoft ReportViewer for your reports?